# Storing multiple checkbox values in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, choicefield

I want to store multiple column values in table.Lets take a example .. What are your favourite colors? the choices can be red,blue,green, orange.  So lets assume, the user selects atleast 2 values.

Is there any way to store the multiple values in table. I have implemented by concatinating choices of users in a column in the table. I later found that it is a bad practise.

Currently i can think of using Bitwise operator  and habtm.

What are the different ways for storing multiple choices values in table?
If I am implementing in rails, What is the best way to implement this with OOP concepts?
Is there any builtin options in rails?

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution is to have a bridging table to create a [many-to-many relationship](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=rails%20many%20to%20many%20relationship).